# Which relative pronoun should I use to describe objects which use the pronoun them?

Tags: relative-clauses

> There are many active political parties here. Many of them hold great influence.

If I were to join both sentences with a preposition and a relative pronoun, would 'which' or 'whom' to describe 'political parties' be more appropriate? When describing similar things, how do I determine between using 'whom' and 'which'?

Comment: I would rewrite that idea to this: *Many political parties are active here and wield great influence over the electorate.*  Since you are new, I helped you but generally this type of question should be asked on ELL. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the US.  One political party, I refer to as "it".  Relative pronoun "which".  Many political parties I refer to as "they".  Sill the relative pronoun I use is "which".

In general, use "who/whom" for people, "which" for everything else.

But note that, in some circumstances, we can use "whose" even for inanimate objects--the possessive relative pronoun like "which's" is missing from English.